# Raspberry Pi 2 GDBus.Error on start up

Tags: raspbian

I just got my new Raspberry Pi 2 and installed RASPBIAN using NOOBs.

On start up I get this error. Its in a message box in the middle of the screen. If I hit ok the GUI seems to work find anyway.

> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject

I have looked around and for similar errors people suggest this to fix the problem

> Preferences->Desktop Session Settings" and un-check "PolicyKit Authentication Agent"

However there is no "Preferences->Desktop Session Settings" that I can find.

Does anyone else with a raspberry Pi 2 have this problem with a fresh install of RASPBIAN? Or do you know where I can find these Preferences.

Thanks

Comment: Same here. Two units, both gave the same error message on first use of startx. Both do not show the error on subsequent starts.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Open LXTerminal.
2. Type `lxsession-edit` to open Desktop Session Settings dialog box.
3. Uncheck LXPolKit.
4. Click OK.
5. Reboot.

---

If no LXPolKit option then try this :

1. Open Terminal.
2. Type `sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/autostart/lxpolkit.desktop`
3. Add the text `LXDE` to the line `NotShownIn`
4. The line should read: `NotShowIn=GNOME;KDE;LXDE`. Save the file afterwards.

*The lx policy kit still runs, it just doesn't report errors ...*

Comment: Thanks skipmonkey that was the window I was looking for :)

Comment: I started seeing this error after installing `xrdp`, this advice fixed it though. Thanks ^_^

Comment: I don't have the LXPolKit item in that window. I show Blueman Applet, GSettings Data Conversion, LXInput autostart, lxkeymap, and Notification Daemon. Everything except GSettings Data Conversion is checked. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: in my system i didn't see the policykit setting in Desktop Session Settings. so only after installing this package "policykit-1-gnome" i saw it and could disable it.