# What does following msg/error mean: GDBus.Error.org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject

Tags: linux, debian

The Title says it all.  We just got a Raspberry 2 with a Debian Linux on it.  After hitting 'Startx' the windows come up and we get this message:

GDBus.Error.org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed:  Cannot determine user of subject

After hitting ok, all seems to work well, **but I'm wondering what it means?**

With the idea that "It's better to teach a man to fish than give him fish", if possible, tell me **where you look these errors up**.  Is it possible to tell if it's Linux, Debian, or Raspberry specific?  As you can probably tell, I'm completely new to Raspberry, Linux, and Debian.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: [Does this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27542/raspberry-pi-2-gdbus-error-on-start-up) solve the problem?  WRT looking them up, stuff like this is usually more of a debugging message; sort of like Windows "Blue screen of death" error codes you might find somewhere to look them up but it probably won't mean much to you.  Ideally you're never suppose to see them and if you do, it's likely some kind of bug -- in this case it looks to be a pretty minor oversight in configuration.

Comment: I'm going to presume this is a duplicate of that.  If it doesn't work, leave an @goldilocks comment and I'll reopen it.  If you want a hint about the mechanism in play, you could start by reading about [freedesktop.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org) and [D-bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus).   Freedesktop focuses on harnessing the heterogeneity of *nix GUI interfaces, which introduces a layer of complexity, and increased complexity increases the possibility of error ;)