# picamera on startx returned with GDBus.Error

Tags: raspicam

I am new to the Raspberry Pi. When I tried to install my picamera, everything went well until I put in the command `startx`. I got the following error:

```
GDBus. Error.org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject
```

Confused if this is...

Comment: I blame `systemd` or one of its "helpers" - but then **I** would and it may not be anything at all to do with it... 8-/

Comment: @SlySven Not related to `systemd` ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 2 GDBus.Error on start up](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27542/raspberry-pi-2-gdbus-error-on-start-up)

Answer (score 1):

Encountered problem before. Here's what to do:

1. Open terminal
2. run `lxsession-edit` (forgot whether to run as root or not)
3. Uncheck "LXPolKit"
4. OK, then reboot.