# VNC: GDBus Error:org freedesktop.PolicyKit1 Error.Failed; An Authentication agent already exixts for the given subject

Tags: vnc, pi-3

I think I am having the same problem as in [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27542/raspberry-pi-2-gdbus-error-on-start-up) thread but none of those solutions work.  I have unchecked the `PolicyKit Authentication Agent` in the `Desktop > Startup > Session` preferences.  I have also added `LXDE` to the `NotShownIn` line of `/etc/xdg/autostart/lxpolkit.desktop`. I also installed `policykit-1-gnome` to get the option to disable `PolicyKit` authentication.  But I am still seeing the error message on VNC log in.

I am running Jessie on an RPi 3.

Answer (score 1):

I could display the "LXPolKit" option in the menu "Desktop Session Settings" by editing the file

```
sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/autostart/lxpolkit.desktop
```

and change the last line by

```
Hidden=false
```

After I restarted the raspberry, I could see and uncheck the "LXPolKit" option. I get rid of the message finally, but I did other things before. So I'm not sure it's the only things to do.